# Serialization among subclass

Tags: java, serialization

In interview it was ask that there is a Class `A` which does not implement the `serializable` interface as shown below

```
class A
{ 
    private int a;

    A( int a)
    {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

and there is a class `B` which extends `A` and also implements the `serializable` interface

```
class B extends A implements serializable
{

    private int a , b;

    B(int a, int b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b; 
    }
}
```

Now please advise whether I can serialize class `B` or not , provided that class `A` is not serialized suppose I want to serialize the object of class `B`, can it be done.

Comment: short answer. Yes, it can be done

Comment: @rai.skumar Thanks but let say If i serialize the class B object then when I deserilize it what would happen , is it the class B constructor will run and what about class A then

Comment: Deserialization doesn't call constructor. Its creates object completely from the encoded stream.

Comment: @rai.skumar can you please post the small example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is not possible to serialize B without modifying A to have an accesible no argument constructor.

From javadoc of [java.io.Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)

> To allow subtypes of non-serializable classes to be serialized, the
> subtype may assume responsibility for saving and restoring the state
> of the supertype's public, protected, and (if accessible) package
> fields. The subtype may assume this responsibility only if the class
> it extends has an accessible no-arg constructor to initialize the
> class's state. **It is an error to declare a class Serializable if this
> is not the case. The error will be detected at runtime.**
>
> During deserialization, the fields of non-serializable classes will be
> initialized using the public or protected no-arg constructor of the
> class. A no-arg constructor must be accessible to the subclass that is
> serializable.

Comment: so we need to provide default constructor to class A first .

Answer (score 4):

> Now please advise whether I can serialize class B or not , provided that class A is not serialized

Yes.

Any class which implement `Serializable` can be serialized. even if it's base class doesn't implement it.

All the classes extend `Object` which is not serializable but still it's sub-classes can be serialized by implementing `Serializable`.

Comment: but what about has a relationship , let say if class b has a reference of class A then.

Comment: `Object` provides a no argument constructor, it wouldn't work without it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, Because your class is implementing the serializable interface that's enough to make your class B as serialized.

Answer (score 1):

Yes; you can serialize class B irrespective of class A.

**Edit:**

```
class A{
int a;
A(int t){
    a =t;
}
A(){}   //default constructor is must
 }

class B extends A implements Serializable{
String b;
B(int t, String u){
    super(t);
    b=u;
}
}

public class SOSerialization {
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("test.ser"));
    B b = new B(1, "tmp");
    os.writeObject(b);
    os.close();
    
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("test.ser"));
    
    Object o = ois.readObject();
    ois.close();
    B bb = (B)o;
    System.out.println(" values :"+ bb.a + "  "+ bb.b);
}
}
```

So you need to provide a default constructor if you want to do deserialization successfully.

**Ouptput :**

values : 0  tmp

So it gets default value of super class attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Of Course.. Here we can Serialize only Class B.. But not A because it's not implemented Serialization interface.

**While Serialization no problem. But while de-serialization only you get runtime error.**

Comment: What's the purpose of serializing without never deserializing?

Comment: @dcernahoschi As the question stated, My answer for that context only applicable. what you said is correct.

Answer (score 0):

of course you can serialize class B as it implements Serializable interface.

**1**-any class which implements Serializable interface can be serialized.

It does not matter base class is Serializable or not .

**2**-If Base class is Serializable then sub class is also Serializable.

**3**-If a object is serialized then it complete object graph will be serialized.
All Objects referenced by instance variables, staring by the object serialized.